# Show two annotation on Xamarin iOS Map simultaneously

Tags: ios, xamarin, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I know, Since I joined StackOver Flow, I am asking regular question, but understand me I in such circumstances where I could get any work around of my issues.

I have situation where On Current Lat-Long I want to annotate Car Image/Icon and pervious Lat-Long I want to annotate Moving Forward Arrow Icon. But I not getting any work around to do so in Xamarin iOS Map.
[This is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGbdS.png)

**exact issue elaborate through image**
[exact issue elaborate through image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxUCJ.png)

I have created custom Map render as well.

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
{
    private CustomMap _formsMap;

    public MKMapView ExtMap { get; private set; }

   
    List<CustomPin> customPins;
    UIView customPinView;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        try
        {
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                //var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                 MKMapView nativeMap = new MKMapView();
                if (nativeMap != null)
                {
                    
                    nativeMap.RemoveAnnotations(nativeMap.Annotations);
                    nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = null;
                    nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView -= NativeMap_DidSelectAnnotationView;
                    nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView -= NativeMap_DidDeselectAnnotationView;
                }
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                _formsMap = (ReplayMap)e.NewElement;
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                ExtMap = Control as MKMapView;
                customPins = _formsMap.CustomPins;
                nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
                nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView += NativeMap_DidSelectAnnotationView;
                nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView += NativeMap_DidDeselectAnnotationView;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.Log(ex);
        }
    }
    private void NativeMap_DidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.View.Selected)
        {
            customPinView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            customPinView.Dispose();
            customPinView = null;
        }
    }
    private void NativeMap_DidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
            customPinView = new UIView();
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.View.Annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }
            double lat = customView.Annotation.Coordinate.Latitude;
            double lon = customView.Annotation.Coordinate.Longitude;
            configureDetailView(customView, customPin);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.Log(ex);
        }
    }
    CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
    {
        var position = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);
        CustomPin pin = new CustomPin();
        try
        {
            if (customPins.Count > 0)
            {

                //Position Position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
                pin = customPins.Where(x => x.Position == position).FirstOrDefault();
                if (pin == null)
                {
                    pin = customPins[0];
                }
                return pin;
                //foreach (var pin in customPins)
                //{
                //    if ((pin.Position.Latitude == position.Latitude) & (pin.Position.Longitude == position.Longitude))
                //    {
                //        return pin;
                //    }
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                pin = customPins[0];
                return pin;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return pin;
        //if (Utility.customPins.Count > 1)
        //{
        //    foreach (var pin in Utility.customPins)
        //    {
        //        if (pin.Position == position)
        //        {
        //            return pin;
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    return Utility.customPins[0];
        //}
        //return null;
    }
    void configureDetailView(MKAnnotationView annotationView, CustomPin pin)
    {
        int width = 150;
        int height = 100;
        var snapshotView = new UIView();
        snapshotView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        snapshotView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        NSDictionary views = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(snapshotView, new NSString("snapshotView"));
        snapshotView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:[snapshotView(175)]", new NSLayoutFormatOptions(), null, views));
        snapshotView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:[snapshotView(150)]", new NSLayoutFormatOptions(), null, views));
        var options = new MKMapSnapshotOptions();
        options.Size = new CGSize(width, height);
        //options.MapType = MKMapType.SatelliteFlyover;
        // options.Camera = MKMapCamera.CameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate(annotationView.Annotation.Coordinate, 250, 65, 0);
        var snapshotter = new MKMapSnapshotter(options);
        snapshotter.Start((snapshot, error) =>
        {
            if (snapshot != null)
            {
                UIView markerInfoBackground = new UIView();
                markerInfoBackground.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                // markerInfoBackground.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black;
                // markerInfoBackground.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.5f;
                // markerInfoBackground.Layer.ShadowRadius = 1.8f;
                markerInfoBackground.Layer.ShadowOffset = new SizeF(0.5f, 0.5f);
             
                markerInfoBackground.Add(imgLocation);
                UILabel lblLocation = new UILabel(new RectangleF(25, 90, width, 30));
                lblLocation.Text = getMapLocation(pin.Position.Latitude.ToString(), pin.Position.Longitude.ToString());
                lblLocation.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12.0F);
                lblLocation.TextColor = UIColor.Gray;
                lblLocation.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
                lblLocation.Lines = 0;
                markerInfoBackground.Add(lblLocation);
                snapshotView.AddSubview(markerInfoBackground);
            }
        });
        annotationView.DetailCalloutAccessoryView = snapshotView;
    }
    public string getMapLocation(string lat, string lng)
    {
        string baseUri = "KEY";
        string location = "N/A";
        string requestUri = string.Format(baseUri, lat, lng);
        try
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string result = wc.DownloadString(requestUri);
                var xmlElm = XElement.Parse(result);
                var status = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
                              where
                                  elm.Name == "status"
                              select elm).FirstOrDefault();
                if (status.Value.ToLower() == "ok")
                {
                    var res = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
                               where
                                   elm.Name == "formatted_address"
                               select elm).FirstOrDefault();
                    requestUri = res.Value;
                    location = res.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return location;
    }


    protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {

        MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;
        MKAnnotationView annotationView1 = new MKAnnotationView();
        try
        {
            if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
                return null;
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }
            CustomPin CustPin = new CustomPin();

            if (annotationView == null)
            {
                annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.ToString());
                annotationView1 = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.ToString());

                OSAppTheme currentTheme = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.RequestedTheme;

                foreach (CustomPin item in _formsMap.Pins)
                {

                    var radians = item.Rotation + 90;
                    if (currentTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark)
                    {
                        annotationView.Image = RotateImage(UIImage.FromFile("car_icon_3.png"), Convert.ToSingle(radians));
                        annotationView1.Image = RotateImage(UIImage.FromFile("darkMode.png"), Convert.ToSingle(radians));
                    }
                    
                    else
                    {
                        annotationView.Image = RotateImage(UIImage.FromFile("car_icon_1.png"), Convert.ToSingle(radians));
                        annotationView1.Image = RotateImage(UIImage.FromFile("Moving.png"), Convert.ToSingle(radians));
                    }
                }
            }
            annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.Log(ex);
        }
        return annotationView;
    }

    public UIImage RotateImage(UIImage image, float degree)
    {
        float Radians = degree * (float)Math.PI / 180;
        UIView view = new UIView(frame: new CGRect(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height));
        CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(Radians);
        view.Transform = t;
        CGSize size = view.Frame.Size;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);
        CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        context.TranslateCTM(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);
        context.RotateCTM(Radians);
        context.ScaleCTM(1, -1);
        context.DrawImage(new CGRect(-image.Size.Width / 2, -image.Size.Height / 2, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height), image.CGImage);
        UIImage imageCopy = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        return imageCopy;
    }
}
```

Android Custom Renderer Code.
Basically what we have done created two object of MarkerOptions. marker and marker2 in Customrenderer and on both markers we have used different images and Assigned one marker to the Google Maps Property.

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using CustomRenderer.Droid;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ReplayMap), typeof(ReplayCustomRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
    [Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class ReplayCustomRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {

        CustomPin customPin;
        List<CustomPin> customPins;
        public new Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap Map { get; set; }

        [Obsolete]
        public ReplayCustomRenderer()
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
                Map.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (ReplayMap)e.NewElement;
                
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
        {
            Map = map;
            base.OnMapReady(map);
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page>(this, "Clear", (value) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //Map = map;
                    //base.OnMapReady(map);
                    Map.Clear();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });
            map.MyLocationEnabled = false;
            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
            Map.MarkerClick += Map_MarkerClick;
        }

        private void Map_MarkerClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs e)
        {
            GetInfoContents(e.Marker);
            e.Marker.ShowInfoWindow();
        }

        protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
            MarkerOptions marker2 = new MarkerOptions();

            try
            {
                marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
                marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
                marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
                marker2.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
                marker2.SetTitle(pin.Label);
                marker2.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
                CustomPin CustPin = new CustomPin();
                CustPin = (CustomPin)pin;
                marker.SetRotation(CustPin.Rotation + 90);
                marker2.SetRotation(CustPin.Rotation + 180);
                OSAppTheme currentTheme = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.RequestedTheme;
                
                 marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromAsset("car_icon_1.png"));
                 marker2.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromAsset("Moving.png"));
                
               
                Map.AddMarker(marker2);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogManager.Log(ex);
            }
            return marker;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem ? Can you provide the actual screen shot to elaborate?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my query with  an Image with exact problem. I hope it helps you understand my issue

Comment: Did you try to add a extra pin with same position but different icon ? What  happened ?

Comment: This is not situation here... there is a loop where which print the annotations on map. But what I need here when loop is exciting initially it should show car icons when loop iterate next last Icon should change to different icons and current loop value should be car Icon.

Comment: Ok，understand , could you show that how you implement on android ? Relevant code will be helpful .

Comment: Hi Colex, Very Sorry for the delay response I was busy with Production task. I have mentioned the Android code now on my above query. Basically what we have done created two object of MarkerOptions. marker and marker2 in Customrenderer and on both markers we have used different images and Assigned one marker to the Google Maps Property.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the pin twice with the same location in Froms project.

And add a extra property to distinguish the pin type and set different icons accordingly .

```
public class CustomPin : Pin
{
    public string PinType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}


CustomPin pin1 = new CustomPin
    {
        PinType = "1",
        Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = new Position(37.79752, -122.40183),
        Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
        Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
        Name = "Xamarin",
        Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
    };

CustomPin pin2 = new CustomPin
    {
        PinType = "2",
        Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = new Position(37.79752, -122.40183),
        Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
        Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
        Name = "Xamarin",
        Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
    };

customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin1,pin2 };
customMap.Pins.Add(pin1);
customMap.Pins.Add(pin2);
```

#### iOS project

```
//GetViewForAnnotation

string image1 = (customPin.PinType == "1")?"car_icon_1.png":"Moving.png";
annotationView.Image = RotateImage(UIImage.FromFile(image1), Convert.ToSingle(radians));
```

Comment: Hi Colex, Very thanks for the response with example. Much appreciated. But similar logic we have also implemented but it did not worked out. What will happen with this logic is that two icon will shown to the same Location, First Car Icon and then Moving.png. Hence it did not work

Comment: According to the screen shot you just need an extra current location with `car_icon_1`, the other locations all are `Moving` image , do I misunderstand ?

Comment: Ok, sorry if I did not explain properly, so we have 600 collection location pins at one go, and what we want that once we do foreach loop upon that collection so at that time on a current pin index location it should show car icon and when foreach loop complete its first iteration so it should  change the icon to the moving.png for that index which became previous index and show car icon to current index again.